# What is a JSF ManagedBean and what role does it play in a three tier client-server framework?

Tags: java, jsf

I have found what it is below, but I cannot seem to find what role is plays in the three tier client-server framework.
We have the browser, web server, and database. Database and webserver are linked by the JDBC layer, but I don't see anything about where the managed bean comes into play.

I assume it gets information entered into a form for example on the front end and helps transfer to the database?

The managed beans can be linked to the UI JSF components so that when, for example, you fill out a form on a web page, the entered values are automatically assigned to the corresponding field in your Java bean. Managed JSF beans are similar to JavaBeans, but the word managed means that they can be linked directly to JSF components. Besides storing data they may also contain information about page navigation.

Comment: JSF itself is a complete MVC framework, targeted to the view layer of the web application. Basically, it performs navigation control, form validations and also does the conversion from-to Java classes (POJOs). The managed bean acts as a controller and is responsible from keeping the model up to date. What role does it play in a three layer application? Let's say you can link it to a stateless class that acts as a service and later on use a DAO or a repository to manage the persistence layer.

Comment: Please read the "Related" section in right hand side and tell which one is acceptable as dupe to this Q.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a JSF ManagedBean?**

> Managed Bean is just an object defined by some class that has a
>   name and scope.

Normally, a bean is model for your view to hold data for the components used on the view and it contains properties for it.

> What role does it play in a three tier client-server framework?

From:
http://craftedsw.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/mvc-and-multi-tier-architecture.html

> In component-centric frameworks like JSF, the pages (generally XHTML) have components that are bound to Java classes (known as backing beans in JSF). 
>   These components can be input texts, drop down lists, tables, etc, or even the entire page. 
>   Basically each component on the page can be bound to a Java class, that would behave like a **Model** and sometimes **Controller** for these components.
>
> The backing beans are responsible to hold the state of the components and also handle events, validation, conversions, trigger business logic, update/refresh other components, fire events, listen to events, etc.